# Reduce gap between product page and footer only?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

My website contains products page like [product page](https://www.wahalengineers.com/product/agitators/) there is big gap between it's description and footer how can i reduce this gap, i'm using *builder69* theme from themeforest.

Answer (score 3):

That's happening because your Related Products have their CSS set to: `visibility: hidden;`.

You have a few options:

1. Show the related products by adding the following to a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)'s CSS:

   ```
   .related.products {
       visibility: visible;
   }
   ```
2. Keep the Related Products, but remove them with CSS by adding the following to your CSS:

   ```
   .related.products {
       display: none;
   }
   ```
3. Disable Related Products altogether with the following in your child theme's functions.php file:

   ```
   remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
   ```

Comment: @UtsavUpadhyay Glad to hear it worked :) Can you please accept my answer (just click  the check mark) so other people who have this problem can also get help?

Answer (score 0):

you have used `visibility:hidden` property,
Use `display:none` instead

use the below code

```
.related.products {
    display: none;
}
```

`display:none` means the content will not appear on the page at all There will be no space allocated for it between the other tags.

`visibility:hidden` means, the content is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page. The content is rendered, it just isn't seen on the page.

Comment: Please accept my answer as answer.. give a green tick